# How to prevent a user from redirecting himself via writing the URL to the login page?

Tags: .net, authentication, authorization

Im looking for a way to prevent already authenticated users from going in the browser search bar and just redirecting themselves back to the login page, i have authorization and authentication implemented and i remove every link to the login page if the user is authenticated however the user can still manually type the URL and redirect himself.

Is there any policy that can stop authenticated users similar to policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser() but the opossite?

Or am i going the wrong way about it?

Answer (score 0):

i used a simple validation on the page onget method, to fix this issue, im redirecting the user to another page, but i might just return him to the current page.

```
public ActionResult OnGet()
    {
        if (User.Identity != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("/Login/AcessDenied");
        }
        else
            return Page();
    }
```